# How to get back the value of a variable passed through different requests in Scrappy

Tags: python, scrapy

Basically, I want to do this:

```
def parseTesT(self, response):
 item = response.meta['item']
 item['another_thing'] = another_value
 return item

def parse(self, response):
 .............
 extract data
 .............
 item = MyItem()
 item['main_url'] = response.url
 request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parseTesT)
 request.meta['item'] = item
 yield request

 # I want to recover my item here and use the value I stored in it in my 'parseTest'
```

but I don't know how to do it...I've looked at this official tutorial, but nothing (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html).

No one knows?

Comment: Is the URL you are requesting to be handled by the `parseTesT` a _different_ URL than the item's `main_url` or is it the same?

Comment: yes, in the example as you see, it's not a different one, but in my real case it's a difference one from the `main_url` one @elacuesta

Comment: What you want to do cannot be acomplished with _vanilla_ scrapy because scrapy is **asynchronous**. I recommend you reorganize your code to do whatever you need to do with the final item in the final callback or with an item pipeline (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html). However, there exists _scrapy-inline-requests_ (https://github.com/rolando/scrapy-inline-requests) which may help in your case.

Comment: mmm ok, I'll take a look at what you've told me, but thank you so much for your answer, at least now I know something about it! And, if you want, post this as the answer, if you want, cos I'll vote it as the final one. You've been the only person that has help through this issue @elacuesta